# Why OpenId with ADFS suddendly stop working?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, .net-core, openid

I'm working on a project which uses openid as one way of authentication. Last week was working just fine, no issues. Suddendly monday morning: **hell**. For no reason all environments DEV, QA, Prod were unable to login using this feature.

There was no deployment, in production a while. All  of these Apps are hosted on Azure App Services

I've checked the configuration, and nothing "apperently" has changed. Funny part: Is working on localhost.

I've spend last two days, debugging, checking logs, but no clues. So ask for help. Any possible clue or hint would be great

**UPDATE**

I've now have more information, that can point somewhere. Everything its ok, with SSO 302 redirect... But this is forcing the browser redirect(and it should) but losing the parameters:

```
#id_token=ey{...}.eyJ{....}.{...}&state=Rn{..}6%3bopenIdConnect%253D1&session_state=558a7d74-e2cf-4e25-86ec-cd0a9f6f500f
```

If the request comes from login.microsoft.org as 302 with the:

```
redirect_url=http://example.com/login#id_token=ey{...}.eyJ{....}.{...}&state=Rn{..}6%3bopenIdConnect%253D1&session_state=558a7d74-e2cf-4e25-86ec-cd0a9f6f500f
```

**The authentication doesn't work** Its seems the appliction suffers some kind of subsquent redirect but if i put the url from the Location Header from login.microsoft

Like this:

```
http://example.com/login#id_token=ey{...}.eyJ{....}.{...}&state=Rn{..}6%3bopenIdConnect%253D1&session_state=558a7d74-e2cf-4e25-86ec-cd0a9f6f500f
```

it works

Here the 302 request headers

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Location: http://example.com/login#id_token=ey{...}.eyJ{....}.{...}&state=Rn{..}6%3bopenIdConnect%253D1&session_state=558a7d74-e2cf-4e25-86ec-cd0a9f6f500f
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
x-ms-request-id: 96fbfb94-5412-460d-b1f9-d9e132bc7d00
x-ms-ests-server: 2.1.12011.8 - NEULR2 ProdSlices
 
Set-Cookie: fpc=ArP_u2aVQNNPkjsfQqhcuB4i0kDOBQAAAJyrytgOAAAA3201hQEAAACeq8rYDgAAAA; expires=Fri, 08-Oct-2021 13:03:56 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; 
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=estsfd; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Date: Wed, 08 Sep 2021 13:03:56 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1756

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://example.com/login#id_token=ey{...}.eyJ{....}.{...}&state=Rn{..}6%3bopenIdConnect%253D1&session_state=558a7d74-e2cf-4e25-86ec-cd0a9f6f500f">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

I'm using burp suite for intercepting the requests, and the only way i manage to make this work its with the option: "Out-of-Scope request"

[Burp Suite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Mc7.png)

This way, i can do all the flow.

Thanks

Comment: Check who was fired recently... and if they had permissions... :) but that is not in scope for SO. For question to be answerable on SO you need to provide much more information, ideally in form of [MCVE].

Comment: Check your certificates expiracy date

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

This was nothing related with SSO or angular, was a thirt party library and SameSite policy was breaking the application flow.

Thanks